# Error: component "zip" not found

Tags: zip, installation, common-lisp, asdf, allegro-cl

I'm trying to install the zip library.

```
wonko:Desktop andrew$ alisp 
International Allegro CL Free Express Edition
8.2 [Mac OS X (Intel)] (Jan 25, 2010 14:49)
Copyright (C) 1985-2010, Franz Inc., Oakland, CA, USA.  All Rights Reserved.
This development copy of Allegro CL is licensed to:
   Allegro CL 8.2 Express user

;; Optimization settings: safety 1, space 1, speed 1, debug 2.
;; For a complete description of all compiler switches given the
;; current optimization settings evaluate (EXPLAIN-COMPILER-SETTINGS).
CL-USER(1): (asdf:oos 'asdf:load-op :zip)              

; Autoloading for package "ASDF":
; Fast loading /Applications/AllegroCL/code/ASDF.fasl
; Autoloading for package "EXCL.OSI":
;   Fast loading /Applications/AllegroCL/code/OSI.fasl
;     Fast loading from bundle code/fileutil.fasl.
;   Autoloading for package "REGEXP":
;     Fast loading from bundle code/regexp2-s.fasl.
;   Autoloading for REGEXP::MAKE-VM-CLOSURE:
;     Fast loading /Applications/AllegroCL/code/regexp2.fasl
;       Fast loading /Applications/AllegroCL/code/YACC.fasl
Error: component "zip" not found
  [condition type: MISSING-COMPONENT]

Restart actions (select using :continue):
 0: Return to Top Level (an "abort" restart).
 1: Abort entirely from this (lisp) process.
[1] CL-USER(2):
```

Specs:

Allegro CL 8.2

ASDF (presumably included with Allegro)

Mac OS X 10.6.4

MacBook Pro 5,1

The weird thing is that ASDF doesn't appear to search online for zip. It just gives up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASDF does not download libraries, you have to get them yourself. ASDF only searches the directories that are in the list asdf:*central-registry* for system definition files (.asd). If you want automatic installation and downloading of libraries checkout [quicklisp](http://www.quicklisp.org/) or [clbuild](http://common-lisp.net/project/clbuild/)